# How do I answer this greedy algorithm question?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, greedy, divide-and-conquer

I am learning greedy algorithm and it's applications. The question below is the first one of the many provided in the book to learn greedy algorithm.

Q) There is n number of children and you have m > n number of chocolate to distribute. You must give
each child exactly one chocolate (of course, you cannot give the same chocolate to two different
children). Each child has an appetite factor ai, 1 ≤ i ≤ n which is the minimum size of a chocolate that the
child will be happy with; and each chocolate has a size sj , 1 ≤ j ≤ m. Your goal is to maximize the
number of happy children, i.e., children i assigned a chocolate j with gi ≤ sj..

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me the solution to this question. There are a few more like this but I think I will be able to do them if i can do this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you yourself in solving the problem? Even a partial solution will help others write a good answer most suited to your question.

Comment: In the question, `greed factor gi` should be `appetite ai`. The word `greed` in the problem statement has nothing to do with the word `greedy` in the title.

Comment: Haven't started with the answer yet but i know we have to assign the cookies in ascending order and whenever possible assign it the least greediest child

Comment: @Mikel Yes, that is the algorithm, and the answer.

Comment: @user3386109 Do i have to write anything else or just the algorithm as the question says? Thanks!

Comment: @Mikel You can write the algorithm in simple steps, as I've shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've correctly identified the algorithm in the comments:

> we have to assign the cookies in ascending order and whenever possible
>   assign it the least greediest child

You can break the algorithm down into simple steps, like this

```
Sort the cookies ascending by size
For each cookie in the sorted list
    if the least greedy child remaining will be happy with that cookie
        give the cookie to the least greedy child
```